# Decimal to hexadecimal conversion using CAPL

Tags: capl

Is there any CAPL function for converting decimal value into hexadecimal value? I have already looked in help option of CAPL browser.

Comment: How do you want to use the converted hexadecimal value?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you want the number to be converted to a string, that you can print out. Either to the write window, into the testreport, etc.

You can use `snprintf` like this:

```
snprintf(buffer,elcount(buffer),"%x",integervariable);
```

where `buffer` is a char array big enough.

This example is taken from the [Vector knowledge base](https://kb.vector.com/entry/496/) and was among the first result on google.

Answer (score -1):

**For hexadecimal equivalent value:**

You can make use of `_pow` function (returns x to the power of y) and `while` in the following way, which would return you the hexadecimal equivalent value:

```
double decToHexEquivalent(int n) 
{
  int counter,remainder,decimal_number,hexadecimal_number  = 0;
  while(n!=0)
  {
    remainder = decimal_number % 16;
    hexadecimal_number = hexadecimal_number + remainder * _pow(10, counter);
    n=n/16;
    ++counter;
  }
  return hexadecimal_number;
}
```

you can call the above function in the following way:

```
testfunction xyz(int n)
{
  write("Hexadecimal:%d", decToHexa(n));
}
```

Caution: not tested

**For hexadecimal value**

declare a global variable `char buffer[100]` in the variable section

```
variables
{
  char buffer[100];  
}
```

and then using `snprintf` function you can convert an integer variable to a character array, like this:

```
void dectohexValue(int decimal_number)
{
  snprintf(buffer,elcount(buffer),"%02X",decimal_number);
}
```

then finally you can use the function as follows:

```
testfunction xyz(int n)
{
  dectohexValue(n);
  write("Hexadecimal:%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Not by executing the code, but by simple thought: What will your code return when you input `10`. I would expect it to return `A`. What does your code return?